# Polymer 1.0 data binding not working

Tags: binding, polymer

I have the following polymer element:

The value of navigator.currentStep is not updating after someMethod is called.

```
<dom-module id="m">
  <template>
    Navigator step = <span>{{navigator.currentStep}}</span>
  </template>
</dom-module>


Polymer({
        is: 'm',
        ready: function() {
          this.navigator = new Navigator(1);
          console.log(this.navigator.currentStep);  // 1
        },
        someMethod: function() {
          this.navigator.next();
          console.log(this.navigator.currentStep);   // 2
}
});
```

Output is always

> Navigator step = 1

But the following works

```
<dom-module id="m">
  <template>
    Navigator step = <span>{{currentStep}}</span>
  </template>
</dom-module>


Polymer({
        is: 'm',
        ready: function() {
          this.navigator = new Navigator(1);
          this.currentStep = this.navigator.currentStep;   // 1
        },
        someMethod: function() {
          this.navigator.next();
          this.currentStep = this.navigator.currentStep;   // 2
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `this.notifyPath('navigator.currentStep', this.navigator.currentStep)`.

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path.

> Sometimes imperative code needs to change an object’s sub- properties directly. As we avoid more sophisticated observation mechanisms such as Object.observe or dirty-checking in order to achieve the best startup and runtime performance cross-platform for the most common use cases, changing an object’s sub-properties directly requires cooperation from the user.
>
> Specifically, Polymer provides two API’s that allow such changes to be notified to the system: `notifyPath(path, value)` and `set(path, value)`, where path is a string identifying the path (relative to the host element).